# How to change the selected value of MS Drop-down list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have used **MS Dropdown list** in my MVC Project. Now I want to change the MS Dropdownvalue using Jquery, How can achieve that? Any Help.

`$("#Country").msDropdown();`

I want to select INDIA using JQuery.  Help me out of this.

Comment: include related code to OP

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can set your default drop down value via using `contains`.

```
$('#Country option:contains("INDIA")').prop('selected',true);
```

**Note : Don't forget to include jquery library  and your code must inside document.ready.**